# Why aren't newlines being printed in this Perl code?

Tags: perl, printing

I have some simple Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;   # not in the OP, recommended
use warnings; # not in the OP, recommended

my $val = 1;
for ( 1 .. 100 ) {
    $val = ($val * $val + 1) % 8051;
    print ($val / 8050) . " \n";
}
```

But when I run it, the output is:

```
bash-3.2$ perl ./rand.pl
0.0002484472049689440.000621118012422360.003229813664596270.08409937888198760.92
... <snipped for brevity> ...
2919250.9284472049689440.3526708074534160.1081987577639750.2295652173913040.1839
751552795030.433540372670807bash-3.2$
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've always seen it as "\r\n", although I'm not sure that makes a difference.

Comment: All these comments about "\r\n" are bogus and have nothing to do with the issue. Perl's handling of newlines is straightforward and well documented.

Comment: Glad it helped. Always put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in your scripts.

Comment: You only need to worry about `\r\n` if you set `binmode()` on the file handle.

Comment: The question was answered properly below. However, the OP should be updated with much cleaner code, using strict and warnings.

Comment: `perl -MO=Deparse,-p` is generally very useful when trying to figure out how Perl is parsing your code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`C:\>` [**`perldoc -f print`**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html):

> Also be careful not to follow the
>   print keyword with a left parenthesis
>   unless you want the corresponding
>   right parenthesis to terminate the
>   arguments to the print--interpose a + 
>   or put parentheses around all the
>   arguments.

Therefore, what you need is:

```
print( ($val / 8050) . "\n" );
```

or

```
print +($val / 8050) . "\n";
```

The statement you have prints the result of `$val / 8050` and then concatenates `"\n"` to the return value of `print` and then discards the resulting value.

Incidentally, if you:

```
use warnings;
```

then `perl` will tell you:

```
   print (...) interpreted as function at t.pl line 5.
   Useless use of concatenation (.) or string in void context at t.pl line 5.
```

Comment: @rlbond: No reason to feel stupid, it's definitely not a pretty aspect of perl. Baroque.

Comment: @Brad thank you for the edit but I rolled back because `<kbd>` does indicate the important fact that the documentation can be accessed on the user's computer.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to use warnings.  Regarding the use of `<kbd>`, I think that this is intended to signify a single keypress, and what you want to convey should just be in `<pre>` tags, perhaps with a prompt character before.

Comment: @Svante: No. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html **KBD:** Indicates text to be entered by the user.

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but I don't know how else to make it and the question is already answered anyway.

Note that using say instead of print neatly sidesteps the whole issue. That is,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $val = 1;
for ( 1 .. 100 ) {
    $val = ($val * $val + 1) % 8051;
    say ($val / 8050);
}
```

works as intended without the issue even coming up. I'm still amazed at how useful say is, given it's such a tiny difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the line is interpreted as follows

```
(print($val / 8050)) . " \n";
```

i.e. the parentheses being used as delimiters for a function argument list, with the ."\n" being silently discarded. Try:

```
 print( ($val/8050) . "\n" );
```

Comment: That didn't work, though I didn't vote you down.

Also, the word you want is "its", not "it's."

Comment: -1 for greengrocers apostrophes? Far too slow with my edit though, Sinan was fast!

Comment: @rlbond: I don't think what you said about "its" and "it's" is right. Though not a native english speaker, I think that "its" is the possesive form of "it", while "it's" is the abbreviation of "it is". So I think that Paul Dixons use of "It's" is perfectly correct.

Comment: No, they were right, I had wrote "Each OS has it's quirks" :)

Comment: @Inshalla: He edited the reply. it's = it is, its = that which belongs to it.

Comment: Ah, that clears it up. Was just looking it up in the dictionary :)

Comment: You only need to worry about `\r\n` if you set `binmode()` on the file handle.

Comment: I downvoted because of the \r\n red herring.  In Perl -- with binmode off -- this isn't ever the issue (echoing Sinan Ünür above).  Edit that out, and this is a correct response and a good line of reasoning.

Comment: @Paul I removed the bit about `"\r\n"` because there is no need to keep wrong information up and there is no need for that to cost you downvotes.