# Why can't I have a literal list slice right after a print in Perl?

Tags: perl, unary-operator

I see I can do something like this:

```
print STDOUT (split /\./, 'www.stackoverflow.com')[1];
```

and "stackoverflow" is printed. However, this:

```
print +(split /\./, 'www.stackoverflow.com')[1];
```

does the same, and this:

```
print (split /\./, 'www.stackoverflow.com')[1];
```

is a syntax error. So what exactly is going on here? I've always understood the unary plus sign to do nothing whatsoever in any context. And if "print FILEHANDLE EXPR" works, I would have imagined that "print EXPR" would always work equally well. Any insights?

Comment: Please change the text of the question to actually be a question about what's going on.  This makes the question more useful to others.

Comment: If you have a suggestion, I would be happy to consider it.

Comment: This deserves to be in the perlfaq. I thought it was already there. :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do not have warnings enabled. In the `print(...)[1]` case, the set of parentheses are regarded as part of the function syntax.

```
print (...) interpreted as function at C:\Temp\t.pl line 4.
```

From, [perldoc -f print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html):

> Also be careful not to follow the print keyword with a left parenthesis unless you want the corresponding right parenthesis to terminate the arguments to the print—interpose a `+`  or put parentheses around all the arguments.

See also [Why aren't newlines being printed in this Perl code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161763/why-arent-newlines-being-printed-in-this-perl-code/1161787#1161787)

Comment: +1 The space in the OP's `print (` is throwing him/her off. Whitespace isn't significant, even if it "looks" significant. This isn't Python.

Comment: This caveat applies to any listop, too! It's just that `print` is the one you're most likely to leave the parentheses off of, and the one you're most likely to accidentally add parens to the first arg of.

Answer (score 8):

`perldoc` for `print` includes this nugget:

> Also be careful not to follow the print keyword with
>   a left parenthesis unless you want the corresponding right
>   parenthesis to terminate the arguments to the print--interpose
>   a "+" or put parentheses around all the arguments.

`print` always evaluates its arguments in LIST context.

To say

```
print (split /\./, 'www.stackoverflow.com')
```

is ok. But when you say

```
print (split /\./, 'www.stackoverflow.com')[0]
```

the parser expects a LIST after it sees the first `(`, and considers the LIST to be complete when it sees the closing `)`. The `[0]` is not interpreted as operating on anything, so you get a syntax error.

```
print "abc","def";       # prints "abcdef"
print ("abc","def");     # prints "abcdef"
print ("abc"), "def";    # prints "abc"
```

---

Other Perl functions that can take a LIST as the first argument behave the same way:

```
warn ($message),"\n"   # \n not passed to warn, line # info not suppressed

system ("echo"),"x"    # not same as system("echo","x") or system "echo","x"
                       #    or system(("echo"),"x")
```